# how do i wait until the receiver channel finishes it's execution in golang?

Tags: go, goroutine

I have this sample code, I am facing this synchronisation problem, could anyone please help me how can I achieve that.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

baseChan := make(chan int)
go func(bCh chan int){
for {
select{
    case stats, _ := <- bCh:
    fmt.Println("base stats", stats)
}}
}(baseChan)

second := make(chan int)
go func (sCh chan int) {
fmt.Println("second channel")
for {
select {
case stats, _ := <- sCh:
    fmt.Println("seconds stats", stats)
    baseChan <- stats
}
}
}(second)
runLoop(second)
}

func runLoop(second chan int) {
 for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
fmt.Println("writing i", i)
    second <- i
}
}
```

actual output:

```
writing i 0
second channel
seconds stats 0

base stats 0
writing i 1
writing i 2

seconds stats 1
seconds stats 2
```

I wanted the output to be something like this,

```
writing i 0
seconds stats 0
base stats 0

writing i 1
seconds stats 1
base stats 1

writing i 2
seconds stats 2
base stats 2
```

Comment: Given you have `fmt.Println("second channel")` in your code, how does it happen your desired output does not have it at all?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would guarantee order of the output messages. So the actual value is certainly expected.

Comment: @zerkms sorry I didn't get you.
That is what I am trying to achieve, how can i control the order of the execution so that  channel A writes to B, Channel B writes to C waits until respective channel finishes its execution.

Comment: Your consumers are not synchronised with the producer, they perform their job independently. If you need the producer to wait while a consumer completed its processing, then you don't need channels and goroutines, just write blocking synchronous code.

Comment: "Channel B writes to C waits until respective channel finishes its execution." --- don't use goroutines and channels, and it would become just function calls naturally.

Answer (score 5):

You *can* write goroutines so that they wait for each other.  For instance, here is a mid-level transporter function that sits between a producer and a consumer and forces them to plod along:

```golang
func middle(in, out chan int, inAck, outAck chan struct{}) {
    defer close(out)
    for value := range in {
        fmt.Println("middle got", value)
        out <- value // send
        fmt.Println("middle now waiting for ack from final")
        <-outAck            // wait for our consumer
        inAck <- struct{}{} // allow our producer to continue
    }
}
```

But this is, in a word, dumb.  It makes no sense to force the producer to wait until the consumer is done **and** use channels, because if we want to make the producer wait, we just write:

```golang
for ... {
    produced_value = producerStep()
    final(middle(produced_value))
}
```

where `producerStep()` produces the next value, and just dispense with the channels entirely.

Still, [here is the complete stepping program on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xr7f1tjb0GU).

Answer (score 0):

The code is working as expected. But one thing you can do, put a certain amount interval between two consecutive steps in `runLoop()` function. But putting a fixed interval is **not recommended**, you need to write some code to make sure that those jobs are completed. Just showing this example, to show you what is happening here.

```golang
func runLoop(second chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println("writing i", i)
        second <- i
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond) // <-- here
    }
}
```

What is happening here? Just giving enough time to complete the jobs that are running in separate goroutines.

Output:

```
writing i 0
seconds stats 0
base stats 0

writing i 1
seconds stats 1
base stats 1

writing i 2
seconds stats 2
base stats 2

writing i 3
seconds stats 3
base stats 3

writing i 4
seconds stats 4
base stats 4
```

Comment: "put a certain amount interval" --- this is the worst way to solve concurrency issues.

Comment: I have tried this, but I don't want to use time.Sleep().
as you suggested above removing the multiple channel logic and aligning it with only one channel implementation. Thanks